# Inflate custom class inside Pager Adapter

Tags: android, android-pageradapter

I am working on a project where I need to implement an infinite scrolling pager adapter. While I have found useful links to implement a two way infinite scrolling view pager similar to the CalendarView( similar in terms of functionality), I am stuck with a small problem. Please have a look the code here.

**Is there a way where I can replace this inside my adapter (extending PagerAdapter)**

```
    @Override
        public Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View mPage = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_layout,null);
             container.addView(mPage );
            return mPage ;
            }
```

**With this**

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position){

       PageLayout page= new PageLayout(context, Integer i, String str);
        container.addView(page);
        return page;

    }
```

**Where**

```
    public class PageLayout extends LinearLayout {

    Integer i;
    String str;

       public PageLayout (Context context, Integer i, String str) {
       super(context);
       View v = inflate(context,R.layout.page,null);
       this.i =i; 
       this.str =str;
       //Find TextViews etc and set them.
       //Perform an asynctask and some other cool stuff

       }
    }
```

So what I need here, is a way to inflate the view extending a LinearLayout ViewGroup in a method within the view class. I need to do this because I want to initialize the Custom View with a few member variables through a constructor and use the same constructor to inflate the layout with the member variables. When I tried this code and debugged the code, the view member of the page is null. Is there a way to do it this way? Am I missing something? Thanks for your help.

**Edit**

The custom view PageLayout has a constructor which takes in a few parameters. PageLayout needs those variables to do perform an asynctask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea is to create a xml layout where you use your custom view.

row.xml could look like that:

```
<my.awesome.package.name.PageLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- just put more useful views here -->
</my.awesome.package.name.PageLayout>
```

You can then easily use it in your PageAdapter like this:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position){
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext());
    PageLayout mPage = (PageLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, container);
    mPage.init("param1", 123); // pass some data to set up the layout
    // to some stuff with other views
    // Also read about ViewHolder pattern if you do not know what it is
    return mPage;
}
```

The error message `Expected resource of type layout` does not mean: `because the ID is not set yet`. The problem is that `getId()` of a layout gives you the `R.id.*` kind of ID and not the kind of `R.layout.*`. Check the generated R class to see that `layout` and `id` are different classes and `inflate()` requires `R.layout.*` ids.

Update:

Your PageLayout can look like that:

```
public class PageLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    public PageLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PageLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PageLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void init(String param1, int param2) {
       // here you can call findViewById(R.id.some_internal_view_ids)
       // and to what ever you want with the parameter
    }
}
```

With that you can access every view you have added inside your `PageLayout` in your `row.xml`. For more details I suggest you read the doc about [Creating Custom Views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)

Comment: There is one other thing, that I need. I need to inflate the layout within the PageLayout class because I need to initialize it with few variables (Context c, Object a) etc. Is there a way I can do with your solution? Thanks!

Comment: I thought my question needed to be more clearer. I updated it.

Comment: You can't create the view via xml with a custom constructor. I would recommend to make a helper method that has the data as parameter and sets the view up. Basically like init() just as public method and with parameters. Than you just need to call it after the inflate method call in the Adapter and you are ready to go.

Comment: Got it. I used a helper method like you said. Will post what I did. If you can update your answer, with what you said, I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I modified the code to show the usage of a helper method.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position){

    PageLayout page= new PageLayout(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)container.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View mPage = inflater.inflate(page.getId(),null);
    return mPage;

}
```

The idea is to inflate your custom's LinearLayout Id. I haven't tried this code, let me know the result.

EDIT

I think the error occurred because the ID is not set yet, i dont really know how to fix that.

What i know will work (because i have done it) is to use the custom layout in the XML (like normally), like this :

```
<com.your.package.PageLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" bla bla />
```

And inflate the XML layout file using `R.layout` like usual.

Comment: I tried this, but I have a problem at the line where we are using page.getId(). Code inspection says "Expected resource of type layout".

Comment: What the.... what are you trying to do here? You mix the concept of inflating xml layouts and creating views programmatically!

Comment: @WarrenFaith sorry i copied the question's code and dont pay enough attention.

Comment: Yeah you just merged code and put it here... sorry it creates more problems than solving the issue

Comment: @trunks175 I have done something like this, what i did back then is to create a custom layout (like yours), and use it in the XML (create new layout normally). Then , i can just use the normal R.layout.id to be inflated. You may want to try that

Comment: @WarrenFaith i just tried to help. And i dont just copy-paste. I dont have access to the code i have written when i answered this question.

Comment: that would have been a good answer. You might want to update your answer and put some useful and correct code in it :)

Comment: @BlazeTama : Yeah, I think R.layout.id might work. Will try and let you know. Thanks!